# Is there any way to use default parameters out of order without having to pass them explicitly in a Python function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

For example, I have this function:

```
def do_something(a=None, b=None, c=None):
    pass
```

Let's say I want to pass only the last parameter to this function, so the call of this function would be like this:`do_something(None, None, 15)`. Is there anyway to do this without passing the first two parameters explicitly?

Comment: `do_something(c=15)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just issue

```
do_something(c=15)
```